# How to setup jadira PersistentLocalDateTime with java.time.LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, jsr

I am trying to persist `java.time.LocalDateTime` using Hibernate and JPA. I used Jadira Framework ("org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA" & "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.extended:3.2.0.GA"). I created `package-info.java` file and created `@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(defaultForType = java.time.LocalDateTime.class, typeClass = org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTime.class)})` there. I tested the solution and the `java.time.LocalDateTime` fields are stored/retrieved to my MySQL database in `DATETIME` columns (**almost**) correctly.

The only problem is that the values in database are +2 hours to the correct time value from fields in Java. I'm in CEST (UTC+2) so I understood that this is some problem with time zones. I debugged the code of `PersistentLocalDateTime` and this is what I found.

1. `PersistentLocalDateTime` is using `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.columnmapper.AbstractTimestampThreeTenColumnMapper`
2. `AbstractTimestampThreeTenColumnMapper` has field `ZoneOffset databaseZone` by default set to `ZoneOffset.of("Z")` (UTC).
3. Because it is thinking that my database is in UTC timezone (and the application is in UTC+2) it adds two hours to my time during conversion to database (and subtracts two hours from my time during conversion from database). So in the application I see the correct date and time but in database I not.

I found that a can add parameters to the `@TypeDef` so I specified them as below:

```
@TypeDef(defaultForType = LocalDateTime.class, typeClass = PersistentLocalDateTime.class,
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "+02:00")
    }),
```

but I've got an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not map Zone +02:00 to Calendar
at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.columnmapper.AbstractTimestampThreeTenColumnMapper.getHibernateType(AbstractTimestampThreeTenColumnMapper.java:59)
```

I debugged a little bit more. `AbstractTimestampThreeTenColumnMapper` has two methods:

```
public final DstSafeTimestampType getHibernateType() {

    if (databaseZone == null) {
        return DstSafeTimestampType.INSTANCE;
    }

    Calendar cal = resolveCalendar(databaseZone);
    if (cal == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not map Zone " + databaseZone + " to Calendar");
    }

    return new DstSafeTimestampType(cal);
}

private Calendar resolveCalendar(ZoneOffset databaseZone) {

    String id = databaseZone.getId();
    if (Arrays.binarySearch(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(), id) != -1) {
        return Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`getHibernateType` method throws the exception because `resolveCalendar` method returns `null`. Why it returns `null`? Because time zones IDs from `java.time.ZoneOffset` and `java.util.TimeZone` does not match. As far as I see the only possible value which match is `Z`. Any other values causes exceptions.

Is there any way to setup this correctly? Or is it a bug in the Jadira Framework?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a serious bug. The problem is that jadira.usertype.databaseZone parameter is parsed to ZoneOffset instead ZoneId. This way, resolveCalendar method compares 2 different types Zone and Offset. What is funny, parameter is named databaseZone but it does not contain zone. It contains only offset.

https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/issues/42

https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/issues/43

Comment: This behaviour is addressed by 5.0.0.GA which maps via ZoneId. Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira.